# Farseer Physics Rigid body when restitution =0

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

how to create a rigid(solid/no bounce) Body in Physics World, I am trying the same with below code

```
Body bodyBall = BodyFactory.CreateBody(world);
CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape(ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(textureWidth / 2f), .1f);
Fixture fixtureBall = bodyBall.CreateFixture(circleShape);
bodyBall.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
bodyBall.Restitution = 0f;
```

though i set restitution 0, it bounces back when it collides with other (same) bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restitution in a collision is a function of the value of the `Restitution` property of ***both*** fixtures.

That function can be customised by modifying code in Farseer, specifically by modifying the `FarseerPhysics.Settings.MixRestitution` method in **Settings.cs**. Here is default implementation, which returns the *maximum* of the two restitution values:

```
public static float MixRestitution(float restitution1, float restitution2)
{
    return restitution1 > restitution2 ? restitution1 : restitution2;
}
```

So you can modify this method (perhaps to return the minimum instead). Or you could simply set the `Restitution` value of all of the involved fixtures to zero.

Comment: Thanks ! just want to know.. Body.Restitution and Fixture.Restitution are same ?

Comment: `Fixture.Restitution` is the *actual* value. `Body.Restitution` is a helper that gets an average of the restitutions of all that body's fixtures, or sets them all to the same value. When using Farseer, I find it helps to build it from source - because it makes this kind of thing easy to check.